# Why Camel Kafka-Rabbitmq connector converts my messages to unreadable format?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect

My goal is to setup a connector between rabbitmq exchange queue and kafka topic.

I was following this guide to setup the connector: https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/latest/try-it-out-locally.html. I downloaded and installed the connector from the source: https://github.com/apache/camel-kafka-connector, built it and unzipped files for `camel-rabbitmq-kafka-connector`. I also pointed `plugin.path` to the folder where I unzipped `camel-rabbitmq-kafka-connector` jars in connect-standalone.properties.

Parameters which I used for the `CamelRabbitSourceConnector` are the following:

```
name=CamelRabbitmqSourceConnector
connector.class=org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.rabbitmq.CamelRabbitmqSourceConnector
tasks.max=1

# use the kafka converters that better suit your needs, these are just defaults:
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

# comma separated topics to send messages into
topics=mytopic

# mandatory properties (for a complete properties list see the connector documentation):

# The exchange name determines the exchange to which the produced messages will be sent to. In the case of consumers, the exchange name determines the exchange the queue will be bound to.
camel.source.path.exchangeName=myexchange
camel.source.endpoint.hostname=myhostname
camel.source.endpoint.addresses=localhost:5672
camel.source.endpoint.queue=myqueue
```

My docker run command for rabbitmq looks like that:
`docker run --rm -it --hostname myhostname -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --name rabbitmq rabbitmq:3-management`. For kafka I used standard "Getting started" guide.

Messages are sent using python Pika library:

```
import pika
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='myqueue',durable=True,auto_delete=True)
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='myqueue', body='some body...')
```

As you can see, I am sending message without specifying `exchange` parameter in `channel.basic_publish` function. If I set it equal to `camel.source.path.exchangeName`, then my message is getting lost somewhere in between, so maybe here I missing something.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly bind `myqueue` to `myexchange` in RabbitMQ?

Comment: I don't know how to explicitly bind them. But looking at the admin console I see that `myexchange` is a `direct` type and routing keys are matching queue name which is `myqueue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing my client to the Java: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html instead of python one.

Comment: Still would be interesting to understand what was different in the python one; could you provide the entire runable python source?

Comment: I pasted the complete example of my python client. I took it from the same guide as Java: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to have it working using the following properties:

```
name=CamelRabbitmqSourceConnector
connector.class=org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.rabbitmq.CamelRabbitmqSourceConnector
tasks.max=1

# use the kafka converters that better suit your needs, these are just defaults:
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

# comma separated topics to send messages into
topics=mytopic

# mandatory properties (for a complete properties list see the connector documentation):

# The exchange name determines the exchange to which the produced messages will be sent to. In the case of consumers, the exchange name determines the exchange the queue will be bound to.
camel.source.endpoint.hostname=myhostname
camel.source.endpoint.addresses=localhost:5672
camel.source.endpoint.queue=myqueue
camel.source.endpoint.autoDelete=false
camel.source.endpoint.skipExchangeDeclare=true
camel.source.endpoint.skipQueueBind=true
```